# $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{ \mathbb{R}^d \setminus A } $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

My attempt: ($A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$) We know by definition that $\overline{A} = \partial A \cup  A $. Hence $\overline{ \mathbb{R}^d \setminus A} = \partial [ \mathbb{R}^d \setminus A ]\cup \mathbb{R}^d \setminus A$. Obviously, have $\partial A = \partial [\mathbb{R}^d \setminus A]$. Hence:

$$  \overline{A} \cap \overline{ \mathbb{R}^d \setminus A } = [\partial A \cup A] \cap[\partial A \cup  \mathbb{R}^d \setminus A ] = \partial A \cup( A \cap \mathbb{R}^d \setminus A) = \partial A \cup \varnothing = \partial A$$

Is this a correct approach? Any feedback would be extremely appreciated. thanks

Comment: It seems correct.

Comment: And your definition of $\partial$ is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of $\partial A$ how obvious $\partial A=∂(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)$ is. If $\partial A$ is defined as the set of points $x$ such that any neighborhood of $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X\setminus A$, then yes, it is obvious.

So your proof is correct.