# Is this a correct way to prove $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

My book has two adjacent exercises, in which $\partial A$ is the set of boundary points of $A$ (a subset of some metric space $X$) and $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$. The first asks me to prove that $\overline{A} = A \cup \partial A$, which was simple and is discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105427/93114).

The second exercise asks me to prove that $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$. I proved this one way that matches the book's solution, but I also have another proof that uses the first exercise, the fact that $\partial A = \partial A^c$, and DeMorgan's Laws.

\begin{align*}
\overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}
&= \left(A \cup \partial A\right) \cap \left(A^c \cup \partial A^c\right) \\
&= \left(A \cup \partial A\right) \cap \left(A^c \cup \partial A\right) \\
&= \partial A \cup \left(A \cap A^c\right) \\
&= \partial A \cup \varnothing \\
&= \partial A
\end{align*}

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: Sounds perfectly correct

Comment: What law is used to go from the second to the third line?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/668831/4280 for basically the same idea.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I used the fact that $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$ (see the [Wikipedia article in union and intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Union_and_intersection)).

Answer (score 1):

For the second,

$\bar{{A}}$ $\cap$ $A^\mathrm{o}$ = ($A^\mathrm{o}\cup\partial{A}$) $\cap$($(A^c)^\mathrm{o}\cup\partial{A^c}$) = $\bar{{A}} \cap ((A)^\mathrm{o})^c$ = $\partial A$

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see how you go from $(A \cup \partial A) \cap (A^c \cup \partial A)$ to the line below it in one step.

I would expand to 4 terms: $(A \cap A^c) \cup (\partial A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap \partial A) \cup (\partial A \cap \partial A)$, where the first term equals $\emptyset$, the final one $\partial A$ and the middle terms $(\partial A \cap A) \cup (\partial A \cap A^c)$ can be regrouped as $\partial A \cap (A \cup A^c) = \partial A \cap X = \partial A$ as well, so the total group becomes indeed $\partial A$.

Of course the definition of the boundary already gives the formula almost directly: $x \in \partial A$ iff every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ (i.e. $x \in \overline{A})$ and every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $X \setminus A = A^c$ (i.e. $x \in \overline{A^c}$. So $\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$, almost by definitions of boundary and closure.